# sending image from java server to android app

Tags: java, android, sockets

I would like to send image file from java server to android app using this code:

Server(Java):

```
File file = new File("./clique.jpg");

FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());        

byte[] contextB = new byte[4096];

int n;
int i = 0;
while ( (n=stream.read(contextB))!=-1 ){
    writer.write(contextB, 0, n);
    writer.flush();
    System.out.println(n);
    i+=n;
}
writer.flush();
stream.close();
```

android app:

```
DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int n;
            int i = 0;
            reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while ( (n=reader.read(buffer)) != null){                
                content.write(buffer, 0, n);
                content.flush();

            }

            Utility.CreateImageFile(content.toByteArray());
```

What I noticed is that in the android app n which is the number of read bytes is not 4096 while I am sending from server byte blocks of 4096 size,also I can not get n=-1 which is the end of stream,it blocks until I close the app then I get n=-1.

Comment: May I ask why you do it that complicated? You could use http to transfer that file which is pretty straight forward. You should call writer.close() instead of writer.flush() after your loop. It should be ok to not receive exact 4k packets, as you are transfering via internet which won't support that large packets.

Comment: I tried also 128 bytes and it also transfers 8 bytes at time

Comment: Did I mention, that you really should use http?

Comment: yes,but using http will not make it smooth and swift. yes its little complicated this way but its effecient

Comment: Well the overhead of http is ok in most cases and it scales way better.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the number of bytes you read at a time has nothing to do with the number of bytes you write -it very much depends on the network conditions and will be variable with every chunk (basically as many bytes managed to be transmitted in short period of time between your reads as many you will get in the read chunk.

Regarding the end of stream - in your server code you have forgotten to close the output stream (you only close the stream which is input stream - you should also close the writer which in turn will close the underlying output stream.

Two comments:

1) I would really recommend to use Buffered Readers/Writers wrapping the writes/readers - the code you will get will be nicer and you will not have to create/manage buffers yourself.

2) Use try {} finally and close your streams in finally clauses - this is the best practice that will make sure that you will close the streams and free resources even in case of problems while reading/writing.

Comment: Could you plz gimme an example of readers writers on my problem? it will be a big help,Thanks a lot

Comment: Closing writer in server side is not a solution at all it closes before the android device finishes receiving all data from writer because server is faster than android device.

Comment: Not really. You should be able to read still the outstanding data... -1.

Comment: really its deosnt gimme the -1

Answer (score 0):

You got a problem in your android code:

```
while ( (n=reader.read(buffer)) != null) {
```

n can not be null.

Use writer.close() instead of writer.flush() after your loop on the server.

Comment: sorry its while ( (n=reader.read(buffer)) != -1) { not I did mistake but the same problem.and if I close writer my socket gonna be closed. and all the blocks I get in the android app I got them less than 4096

Comment: Does it work when you close the socket by closing the writer? Due to network latency your android side loop may receive -1 on .read() before all data got transfered because no data is in the receiver-buffer (as tha data is still on route to your phone). You should try an alternate exit condition for your loop.

Comment: my loop in the server sde closes and moves to the next lines however in the android app it doent receive -1 at alll and it stops in the last block that should finishes it ,I mean in the android app it misses the last block then get n = -1 to finish all. By closing the writer I loose everything (client socket , and loose the rest data on route)